# Print first element in list using Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I print the first element in list using Scala?

For example in Python I can just write:

```
>>>l = [1,2,3,4]
>>>one = l[0]
>>>print one
```

How can I do that on Scala

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Hiura said, or like this:

```
object ListDemo extends App {
    val lst = List(1, 2, 3)
    println(lst(0)) // Prints specific value. In this case 1.
                    // Number at 0 position.
    println(lst(1)) // Prints 2.
    println(lst(2)) // Prints 3.
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Basically, your python code is equivalent of:

```
scala> val l = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val one = l.head
one: Int = 1

scala> println(one)
1
```

(Run in the scala interpreter.)

[Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) is the documentation about Scala's List.

---

It was asked as a subsidiary question «how do I display each element?».

Here is a recursive implementation using pattern matching:

```
scala> def recPrint(xs: List[Int]) {
     | xs match {
     |     case Nil => // nothing else to do
     |     case head :: tail =>
     |         println(head)
     |         recPrint(tail)
     | }}
recPrint: (xs: List[Int])Unit

scala> recPrint(l)
1
2
3
4
```

As David Weber pointed out in the comments, if you cannot use a recursive algorithm to visit your list's elements then you should consider using another container, because accessing the i-th element of a `List` takes O(N).

Comment: yeah but how can i print second or third element in list?

Comment: Well, that was another question ;-)
You can either use the `apply` method (like in Brano88's answer), or recurse on the tail of the list.

Comment: If you can traverse the list from head to tail, then recurse away. If not, you are using the wrong data structure as apply is O(N) for lists. Use Vector or Array instead.

Comment: @DavidWeber that's a very good point. I've included it in my answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Answer can easily be found in [scaladoc for list](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)

```
def head: A
Selects the first element of this list.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we have created an object (Object name: TestList) which containing variable myList.

```
scala> object TestList{
     |       def main(args: (Array[String])){
     |       var myList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
     |       println("Complete List is : "+myList)
     |       println("Reverse List : "+myList.reverse)
     |       println("Print Send Element from list : " + myList(1))
     |       println("Print First three element : "+ myList.take(3))
     |       println("Remove First two element : "+myList.drop(2))
     |       }
     |       }
```

defined object TestList

Calling object with main Method

```
scala> TestList.main(Array(""))
```

OUTPUT:

```
    Complete List is : List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    Reverse List : List(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
    Print Send Element from list : 2
    Print First three element : List(1, 2, 3)
    Remove First two element : List(3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks